# define css properties with jquery before using css transition issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I've found that there seems to be a problem using css transitions properties when they are initially set to auto. To circumvent this I've set the initial css properties using jquery, before adding the css transition property.

The issue I'm having is that when I define the transitional properties immediately after setting the initial css properties, I get weird behaviour. **EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/3zUDc/10/

However, when I delay setting the transitional properties by a few milliseconds, I get the intended behaviour, but the code seems uglier. **EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/3zUDc/9/

Is there a way to accomplish the behaviour seen in the second example without putting the css transitions and destination parameters in the setTimeout block?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: +1 Nice examples...Keen to know the answers...

Comment: @Tuck have you tried $('a:first').show().css( ?

Comment: Ya `.show()` works... @AlexBall

Comment: @Tuck, perfect, Wassim has post the answre ;-)

Comment: Awesome! That works great. Can you explain why it works? I don't really understand the theory behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** is an answer...

```
$('a:first').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'width': $(this).width() / $(this).parent().width() * 100 + '%', 'height': $(this).height()});
    $('a:first').show().css({
        '-webkit-transition': 'all 3s', 
        '-moz-transition': 'all 3s', 
        width: '100%', 
        height: '100px', 
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    });
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3zUDc/11/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.css('left')` to the end of your css declaration: http://jsfiddle.net/YDt7G/

The reason this works (or doesn't work) is because the browser's javascript engine optimises code that changes the DOM. So it doesn't update the DOM instantly after every line of code and is basically putting all the code into one DOM update.

Adding the `.css('left')` forces browser's javascript engine to look at the DOM and in-turn update the DOM beforehand.